# How do I parse each letter of an Arabic text string in .NET C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio, localization

Why while I loop over every single char of this .NET C# string `Arabic text: ٻڠڣڟگگښڏ` at position 13<sup>th</sup> I get the wrong letter? 'ٻ' instead of 'ڏ'.

How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please include formatted code as text, not as a screen shot.

Comment: In addition to converting your screen shot to text, can you convert the string to a `char[]` and show the individual chars as integers (in hex, please).  That way we can figure out what's going on.  Arabic can be tricky, in addition to being RTL, there are multiple representations of the same letter, depending on whether they are before or after a "space".  Then, there are things like the soft vowels that appear kinda-sorta like accents, and letters like hamza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arabic is written right-to-left. The arrow points to the character at offset 20.

You're pointing to the last

```
 0: U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
 1: U+0072 LATIN SMALL LETTER R
 2: U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A
 3: U+0062 LATIN SMALL LETTER B
 4: U+0069 LATIN SMALL LETTER I
 5: U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C
 6: U+0020 SPACE
 7: U+0074 LATIN SMALL LETTER T
 8: U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E
 9: U+0078 LATIN SMALL LETTER X
10: U+0074 LATIN SMALL LETTER T
11: U+003A COLON
12: U+0020 SPACE
13: U+067B ARABIC LETTER BEEH
14: U+06A0 ARABIC LETTER AIN WITH THREE DOTS ABOVE
15: U+06A3 ARABIC LETTER FEH WITH DOT BELOW
16: U+069F ARABIC LETTER TAH WITH THREE DOTS ABOVE
17: U+06AF ARABIC LETTER GAF
18: U+06AF ARABIC LETTER GAF
19: U+069A ARABIC LETTER SEEN WITH DOT BELOW AND DOT ABOVE
20: U+068F ARABIC LETTER DAL WITH THREE DOTS ABOVE DOWNWARDS
```

---

And that's not going into the fact that a grapheme (visual element) can be composed from multiple Unicode Code Points, and that C# uses surrogate pairs and thus multiple `char` values to represent some Unicode Code Points.

For example, there exists a script where the following grapheme exists:<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSNEY.png)</sup>

[image: A glyph with a dot below it]

- The grapheme is formed from the Unicode Code Points U+11A0B followed by U+11A33.
- C# encodes U+11A0B as chars 0xD806 followed by 0xDE0B.
- C# encodes U+11A33 as chars 0xD806 followed by 0xDE33.

So the grapheme would be represented by the following sequence of four `char` values!

1. 0xD806
2. 0xDE0B
3. 0xD806
4. 0xDE33

---

And no, it's not just for archaic languages. "" is used daily by many people.

- The grapheme is formed from the Unicode Code Point U+1F600.
- C# encodes U+1F600 as chars 0xD83D followed by 0xDE00.

---

1. I'm not familiar with the script in question, so I don't know if this character makes sense in practice. But if this one doesn't, other similar characters do make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation: do you know how to correctly parse a string like this?

Comment: All that info (directionality, whether a character is mark) is in the Unicode database. And Unicode provides the algorithms to how to draw stuff, how to identify graphemes, etc. So you would need a library that provides that info and tools. (Well, you could do it yourself; the info is all freely available.) /// As for code points that require surrogates in C#, that's any code point over 0xFFFF. The Wikipedia page on UTF-16 shows how they're encoded.